# Merging Object and List with Lambdas

Tags: list, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a situation similar to the follows:

```
List<ObjectA> all = repository.findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "status"));
```

This find a list of object with three possible states: *OPEN*, *CLOSED*, *PROGRAMMED*

Now I must return a List that shows to the user the last PROGRAMMED object, the first OPEN object and all closed objects. I have writing something like that:

```
ObjectA programmed = all.stream().filter(isPROGRAMMED()).reduce((x,y) -> y).orElse(null);
ObjectA open = all.stream().filter(isOPEN()).findFirst().get();
List<ObjectA> closed = all.stream().filter(isCLOSED()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`isOPEN()`, `isPROGRAMMED()` and `isCLOSED()` are Predicate I have written as follows:

```
private static Predicate<ObjectA> isPROGRAMMED() {
    return x -> x.getStatus().equals(Stato.PROGRAMMED);
}

private static Predicate<ObjectA> isOPEN() {
    return x -> x.getStatus().equals(Stato.OPEN);
}

private static Predicate<ObjectA> isCLOSED() {
    return x -> x.getStatus().equals(Stato.CLOSED);
}
```

Now I want just to merge the two object and the third list into one. List should contain programmed item (if present) open object (if present) and after that all closed items. I jave tried with `Stream.of`, `Stream.concat` but I always obtain some compilation errors..

Are there some way to do it with Lambdas and with few code?

Comment: `List should contain` - that doesn't require the usage of streams.  `list.add(0, open):` then `list.add(0, programmed):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid mutation of the `closed` list, then `Stream IPA` is one of the possible choices for this task.

It could be done like this:

```
    public static List<ObjectA> merge(List<ObjectA> closed, ObjectA programmed, ObjectA open) {
        return Stream.concat(Stream.of(programmed, open), 
                             closed.stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

And as I've already mentioned in the comment if are not concerned about preserving the initial state of the `closed` list, then these objects can be added directly to the list. Since adding a new element at the beginning of the list is costly (if it's backed by the array), a better option will be make use of `addAll()` and add both values in one operation as [**Holger**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) suggested :

```
        closed.addAll(0, Arrays.asList(programmed, open));
```

**Side note:**

- There's an inconsistency in how you are obtaining a `programmed` object and `open` object. If a `programmed` object doesn't exist your decided to return `null`. But if there's no `open` object, method `get()` will raise `NoSuchElementException`.

```
ObjectA programmed = all.stream().filter(isPROGRAMMED()).reduce((x,y) -> y).orElse(null);
ObjectA open = all.stream().filter(isOPEN()).findFirst().get();
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander! Yes I have already tried the solution `list.add(0, object)` but I wounted to find out if a lambda solution was less verbose!

Comment: @CoderJammer well, it's relatively concise. Its main advantage is that doesn't mutate the source of data. You could also replace `collect(Collectors.toList())` with `toList()` if you are using the latest version of Java.

Comment: Mind that `add(0, …)` on an `ArrayList` has to copy all elements from this index and above to a new position and doing it twice in a row on index zero means copying the entire list twice. So it’s preferable to use `closed.addAll(0, Arrays.asList(programmed, open));` as its not only a single statement but also avoiding the unnecessary copying overhead. When you are using Java 9 or newer and know that neither, `programmed` nor `open`, is `null`, you can use the even better `closed.addAll(0, List.of(programmed, open));`.

Comment: @Holger that's a good point with `addAll`! I'll edit the answer. Method List.of() is null-hostile and it seems like `programmed` could be `null`, so in the absence of clarifications from the PO `Arrays.asList` looks like a better option.